# swapping column from a text file in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am having some problems with this code. I need to write a code where it says `SwapField` to display columns from a text file and swaps column 2 to be column 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lineNum = 0;
    String delimiter = " ";

    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("USAGE:  java SwapColumn fileName column#  column#");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    String dataFileName = args[0];
    String columnAText = args[1];
    String columnBText = args[2];
    int columnA = Integer.parseInt(columnAText);
    int columnB = Integer.parseInt(columnBText);

    File dataFile = new File(dataFileName);
    Scanner input;
    String outputText = null; 
    System.out.printf("dataFileName=%s, columnA=%d, columnB=%d\n",
            dataFileName, columnA, columnB);
    try {
        input = new Scanner(dataFile);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String inputText = input.nextLine();
            lineNum++;

            outputText = swapFields(inputText, columnA, columnB, delimiter);
            System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", lineNum, outputText);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException FNF) {
        System.out.printf("file not found: %s\n", dataFileName);
    }
}

static String swapFields(String input, int fieldA, int fieldB, String delim) {
    String outputBuffer = "";
   //code needed here

    return outputBuffer;
}
```

Comment: So you want to swap 2 columns and then write the data back to the same file?

Comment: I already have the data written in the text file. I would like to display the 3 columns first and then swap the order of the columns. Yes i would like to write back to the file.

Comment: This is how the text file looks. I would like to diplay Thomas jefferon instead of Jefferson Thoms.
 Jefferson Thomas 
 Adams Samuel

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you want the method to take in a `String input` delimited by `delim`, and swap fields `fieldA` and `fieldB`?

```
static String swapFields(String input, int fieldA, int fieldB, String delim) {
    String[] bits = input.split(delim);
    String temp = bits[fieldA];
    bits[fieldA] = bits[fieldB];
    bits[fieldB] = temp;
    return String.join(delim, bits);
}
```

In this code, the `.split()` method breaks the `input` up into an array, using `delim` as the separator (interpreted as a regular expression; see below for the assumptions regarding this). The two relevant (zero-indexed) fields are then swapped, and the `String` is reconstructed using `.join()`.

Note that the last line (the `.join()`) requires Java 8. If you don't have Java 8 then you can use `StringUtils.join` from Apache Commons Lang.

I am also assuming here that your `delim` is in the right format for the `.split()` method, which is to say that it's a string literal that doesn't contain escapes and other regex characters. This seems like a plausible enough assumption if it's a delimiter in a text file (usually a comma, space or tab). It further assumes that the delimiter doesn't occur elsewhere in the `input`, within quotes or something. You haven't mentioned anything about quotes; you'd need to add something to clarify if you wanted to be able to handle such things.

Comment: thank you for your response. I appreciate it. This code works fine, but how about if I want to use string BufferOutput = "", and return BufferOutput the display the same data without swaping.

Comment: @nabil I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.